# TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

i have an array :

```
content =    [ { title : 'Canal notifications' , subtitle: ['Notification Push','Email']} , { title : 'Canal notifications' , subtitle: ['Notification Push','Email']} ];
```

i want to iterate this array using ngFor :

```
   <app-toggle-element *ngFor="let element of content; let i = index" [title]="element[i]['title']" [subtitle]="element[i]['subtitle'][i]" ></app-toggle-element>
```

i get this error :

> Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Comment: Why you again fetch subtitle of `i` in `[subtitle]="element[i]['subtitle'][i]"` ?

Comment: You are iterating through the array and trying to access the current element's index which is wrong. You can use it  **element.title **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the `*ngForOf` structural directive which is responsible to add your HTML in existing DOM elements.

And also the iteration variable `element` that you used in `*ngForOf` repeater is represent the current iteration data which contains your `title` and `subtitle` also,

So instead of fetching `title` and `subtitle` with array indexing, you can use the data contains in above iteration variable like,

Here doesn't know why you fetch the current index subtitle, but I have added here **[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-incmlg?file=src/app/app.component.html)** with your requirement

```
<app-toggle-element *ngFor="let element of content; let i = index" [title]="element.title" [subtitle]="element.subtitle[i]" >
</app-toggle-element>
```

**[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-incmlg?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
[title]="element.title"
```

You are iterate through array. In `element` variable is the current element of iteration.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use your notation is should be:

```
[title]="content[i]['title']
```

but there is no point in that as you have `*ngFor`, and as stated in the previous answer you should use:

```
[title]="element.title"
```

however, with the current setup you cannot have both values of the `subtitle` array `['Notification Push','Email']` dynamically, as your `*ngFor` is going through every object and not the array. So with the above setup you will get:
`subtitle=Notification` for the first object and `subtitle=Email`  for the second.

think about changing your setup